# ionic 3 make close button overlap top right corner of modal

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to make a close button and position the center of button on the top-right corner of a modal, which means part of the close button will out of the modal.
I have set the scss of the close button as below:

```
.closeBtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        right: -20px;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
```

However, it doesn't work.
I investigate why and found modal in ionic have set 2 parents div

```
overflow: hidden
```

So part of the close button will not be shown.
Hence, how can I make part of the close button out of the modal size?

Comment: make overflow visible of parent div

Comment: as the overflow hidden property are set in ionic, so I don't have control of the parent divs

Comment: yes we can change ionic css using overriding those classes in our  styles.css file

Comment: then it will override all modal css, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the overflow property to make it visible.

If you want to change styles for the modal container without changing styles to all modals you can pass a `cssClass` property within the options parameter on the modalController.create method like this:

```js
this.modalController.create('MyModalPage', {}, {cssClass: 'my-modal-class'})
```

You can check this in the ionic docs: [Modal Controller api docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)